# How can I get distinct id columns to prevent repeated results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id, name, floors, rooms, bathrooms, 
    singlebeds, doublebeds, tollboys, tvs, 
    conditontypes_id, roomtypes_id, roomstates_id, 
    internet, carstop, elevator, cleanservice, 
    phoneguide, botagaz, magazeen, maqroeev, salahdir, 
    clotheswasher, foodlist, makoa, thalaga, foodtable, 
    saala, kitchen, notations, stopstate, contract_id, 
    enterstate, aqed_id, aqedtype, datefrom, dateto, daynumber, 
    monthnumber, room_name, roomprice, cus_name, company, 
    discounttitle, discounttype, discountprice, total, totalend, 
    aqed_note, addeddate, entertime, state, nationalname, 
    sejelnumber, diffarest, diffbusy, dayprice, monthprice, hourprice
FROM            
    rooms_monitorview
WHERE
    (state IS NULL) OR
    (state = 'محجوز') AND (diffarest < 0)
```

This is the result

```
12  102 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   ....    False   0   شاغر    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
14  104 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   ....    False   0   شاغر    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
15  105 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   ....    False   0   شاغر    15  يومي    25/09/2017  02/10/2017  10  0   105 0.0000  سالم علي محمد   بدون    بدون    $   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  ............    22/09/2017 10:35:24 م   NULL    محجوز   سعودي   123456  -2  -9  0.00    0.00    0.00
15  105 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   ....    False   0   شاغر    16  يومي    28/09/2017  28/09/2017  5   0   105 0.0000  سالم علي محمد   بدون    بدون    $   0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  ............    23/09/2017 01:31:21 ص   NULL    محجوز   سعودي   123456  -5  -5  0.00    0.00    0.00
16  106 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   ....    False   0   شاغر    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I need distinct `id=15` - how can I do this?

There are two different results, -3 and -9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` if you want only one row per id:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (SELECT v.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) as seqnum
      FROM rooms_monitorview
      WHERE (state IS NULL OR state = 'محجوز') AND diffarest < 0
     ) v
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Noticed that I added parentheses to the `WHERE` conditions.  This logic is slightly different from your logic, but this might be what you really want.

Comment: SELECT        v.*
FROM            (SELECT        i.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                           ORDER BY id) AS seqnum
FROM            rooms_monitorview AS i
WHERE        (state IS NULL) OR
                         (state = 'محجوز') AND (diffarest < 0)) v
WHERE        seqnum = 1;